# Fail to import Phoenix npm package in overmind graphql

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, phoenix-framework, absinthe

I re-installed all node modules using `npm install` run into the error:
 `Cannot find module 'phoenix' from 'node_modules/@absinthe/socket/compat/cjs/index.js'`

It fails first in the @absinthe code:
`require('phoenix');` in @absinthe/socket/compat/cjs/index.js

but overmind-graphql relies on phoenix as well and the IDE shows a broken import:
`import { Socket as PhoenixSocket } from 'phoenix';` in this [line in overmind-graphql](https://github.com/cerebral/overmind/blob/8b0af15ba79870c7086e9bc80cb99ec5aed88ca8/packages/overmind-graphql/src/index.ts#L5)

The relevant package versions I have installed for this:

```json
"overmind": "^28.0.1",
"overmind-graphql": "^8.0.1",
"overmind-react": "^29.0.1",
"phoenix": "^1.6.0",
"@absinthe/socket": "^0.2.1",
"graphql": "^15.5.1",
"graphql-react": "^15.0.0",
"graphql-tag": "^2.12.4",
"react": "^17.0.1"
```

I tried:

- "phoenix" and "@absinthe/socket" were dependencies before, so I manually installed them
- remove all node_modules and re-install all packages
- remove package-lock.json, node_modules and re-install all packages
- removing the import of overmind in my React component: no errors because it doesn't reach the failing phoenix import
- run `next build` and `next start` instead of the always reloading `next dev`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is using the specific version of the phoenix package that overmind-graphql relies on:
`"phoenix": "1.4.13"`

Seems like the re-install didn't help, but just confused me more.